# Type error: Type 'x' is not assignable to type 'x' (on vercel deployment)

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I get an error on vercel deployment which says:

### -

> Type error: Type ' ({ params }: DashboardPageProps) = Promise' is not assignable to type
> 'FC<.DashboardPageProps>'
>
> Type 'Promise‹Element>' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>

this is the `./app/(dashboard)/[storeId]/(routes)/page.tsx` file:

```js
// imports

interface DashboardPageProps {
    params: { storeId: string }
}

const DashboardPage: React.FC<DashboardPageProps> = async ({
    params
}) => {
const totalRevenue = await getTotalRevenue(params.storeId);
    const salesCount = await getSalesCount(params.storeId);
    const stockCount = await getStockCount(params.storeId);
    const graphRevenue = await getGraphRevenue(params.storeId)

    return (
     //content
    )
```

this is the repository: https://github.com/volfcan/ecommerce-admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `React.FC` is used with ordinary (client) React components, in your code DashboardPage seem to be server component (returning promise) and thus isn't compatible with `React.FC`. To make error go away you just need to remove `React.FC`